# Background Colour - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to change the background of the whole canvas, this is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
screen = tk.Canvas(root)
screen.grid()


    class Digit:
        def __init__(self, canvas, x=10, y=10, length=20, width=4, background='cyan'):
            self.canvas = canvas
            l = length
            self.segs = []
            for x0, y0, x1, y1 in offsets:
                self.segs.append(canvas.create_line(
                    x + x0*l, y + y0*l, x + x1*l, y + y1*l,
                    width=width, state = 'hidden'))
        def show(self, num):
            for iid, on in zip(self.segs, digits[num]):
                self.canvas.itemconfigure(iid, state = 'normal' if on else 'hidden')
```

I've have tried putting the defining the background colour in different places, however nothing will change the colour. I have tried defining the background in the `canvas.create.line` but still had no luck.
I also had it defined as `root.configure(background='cyan')` but this also didn't work.

Running pyton 3.7 (if this helps)

Where should it be if where it is currently is not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this? The following code changes background of the canvas-screen

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
screen = tk.Canvas(root, bg="cyan") # <--- bg="cyan"
screen.grid()
root.mainloop()
```